# Flag declined claiming a source is rightly criticized in an answer because it is used in the Q, but I don't see it in the Q

Tags: discussion, support, moderation, flagging

I flagged [this answer](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/86207/18373) for a minor issue:

> Since there's a recent mod trend to remove irrelevant soapboxing from answers, I suggest the last para on Meduza be removed. AFAICT Meduza was never brought up by the question. – Dolphin 613 Motorboat Mar 11 at 11:56

but a mod

> Declined - Meduza is the source used in the question. The author of the question pointing out possible biases of the source they used is a valuable addition to the answer.

I however cannot see where Meduza is used in the Q. There are two links with large quotes in the Q: one to [FT](https://www.ft.com/content/f0d3223a-7f4d-11e8-bc55-50daf11b720d) and one to [AP](https://apnews.com/article/269b3de1af34e17c1941a514f78d764c). There's also a mention of Wikipedia and an apparent quote in the Q, but w/o a link. And just in case the mod was so diligent but I wasn't, I even tracked down what Wikipedia cites that from, and it's the *New Yorker*:

[image]

So where is Meduza "the source used in [the **question**](https://politics.stackexchange.com/posts/86205/revisions)"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a mistake in that flag-comment. I wrote "question" but I meant "answer". The first link in the answer is `https://meduza.io/feature/2022/05/31/ya-prosila-snyat-mamu-s-tsepi-no-oni-otkazalis`.

Comment: Mkay, next time I want to cast doubt on something, I'll quote some Russian/DPRK/China state source as saying it. And tack a para about the lack of freedom of press there. Thus implying that it can't possibly be true because those sources say it. I learn some new propaganda "how to" every day here.

Comment: @Dolphin613Motorboat you should probably comment that on the main site and ask the author to change their answer (or just make the edit yourself if it doesn’t change the answer’s argument)

Comment: @EkadhSingh-ReinstateMonica: there's nothing to change--the whole answer is just that.

Comment: @Dolphin613Motorboat the answer could probably be fixed by saying that is how certain countries would view it